# How do I get the menu that has flashing, speed, type and scale? (Picture below)

Tags: performance, rotation, blender

I'm relatively new to Blender, my version - 3.1.2
I was looking for a way to change the rotation speeds of objects and I couldn't find anything then I came across this video on YT, but he hasn't left a tutorial
Does someone know how to get that menu
Any help is welcome

**Menu highlighted in red**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's this paid addon: https://blendermarket.com/products/strobe-light-

But you can also animated it without it by animating rotation of the lamp (object) and its light power.